# Put event markers on table_calendar widget

Tags: flutter, calendar

I am trying to implement the table_calendar widget in my Flutter app.

In all the videos I have watched on YouTube, no one is storing the events in a Firebase db but I think this is necessary so I don't lose the events once the app is shut down.

Ok, that's not really my problem.

I am trying to put a marker on any day on the calendar with an event associated with it but I am stuck.

Here is my code:

```
final kNow = DateTime.now();
final kFirstDay = DateTime(kNow.year, kNow.month - 3, kNow.day);
final kLastDay = DateTime(kNow.year, kNow.month + 12, kNow.day);

final _db = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
bool showSpinner = false;
DateTime? _selectedDay;
DateTime _focusedDay = DateTime.now();
LinkedHashMap<DateTime, List<Events>> kEvents =
    LinkedHashMap<DateTime, List<Events>>();

class AppointmentCalendarScreen extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {
  const AppointmentCalendarScreen({Key? key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String? title;

  @override
  ConsumerState<AppointmentCalendarScreen> createState() =>
      _AppointmentCalendarScreenState();
}

class _AppointmentCalendarScreenState
    extends ConsumerState<AppointmentCalendarScreen>
    with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  late final ValueNotifier<List<Events>> _selectedEvents;

  late StreamController<Map<DateTime, List>> _streamController;
  var eventDoc;
  var trxnDoc;
  Map<DateTime, List>? eventsMap;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _streamController = StreamController();
    _selectedDay = _focusedDay;
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    //_selectedEvents.dispose();
    _streamController.close();

    super.dispose();
  }

  List<Events> _getEventsForDay(DateTime day,
      [List<Events>? events, List<Trxn>? trxns]) {
    // kEvents is a linkedHashMap
    // Calendar events
    for (int i = 0; i < eventDoc.length; i++) {
      DateTime eventDate = eventDoc[i].eventDate;
      DateTime eventDateUTC = eventDate.toUtc();
      if (day.year == eventDate.year &&
          day.day == eventDate.day &&
          day.month == eventDate.month) {
        List<Events> eventList = [];
        eventList.add(eventDoc[i]);

        return (kEvents.putIfAbsent(eventDateUTC, () => eventList));
      }
    }
    return [];
  }

  void _onDaySelected(DateTime selectedDay, DateTime focusedDay) {
    if (!isSameDay(_selectedDay, selectedDay)) {
      setState(() {
        _selectedDay = selectedDay;
        _focusedDay = focusedDay;
      });
      _selectedEvents = ValueNotifier(_getEventsForDay(selectedDay));
    }
  }

  void _onVisibleDaysChanged(
      DateTime first, DateTime last, CalendarFormat format) {}

  void _onCalendarCreated(
      DateTime first, DateTime last, CalendarFormat format) {}

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      body: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
        children: <Widget>[
          StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
            stream: _db
                .collection('users')
                .doc(ref.read(globalsNotifierProvider).currentUserId)
                .collection('events')
                .where('eventDate', isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: kFirstDay)
                .where('eventDate', isLessThanOrEqualTo: kLastDay)
                .snapshots(),
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
              // Handle any errors
              if (snapshot.hasError) {
                return Center(
                  child: Text('Error fetching data: ${snapshot.error}'),
                );
              }

              // Handle loading data
              if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
              } else {
                if (snapshot.hasData && snapshot.data!.docs.isNotEmpty) {
                  List<Events> eventsList = [];
                  for (var snapshotEvent in snapshot.data!.docs) {
                    Events event =
                        Events.fromJson(snapshotEvent.id, snapshotEvent.data());
                    eventsList.add(event);
                  }
                  return _buildTableCalendar(eventsList);
                } else {
                  return _buildTableCalendar();
                }
              }
            },
          ),
          const SizedBox(height: 8.0),
          //_buildButtons(),
          ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () async {
              setState(() {
                showSpinner = true;
              });
              try {
                ref.read(globalsNotifierProvider.notifier).updatenewEvent(true);

                Navigator.of(context).push(
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => AddEventScreen()));

                setState(() {
                  showSpinner = false;
                });
              } catch (e) {
                // todo: add better error handling
                //print(e);
              }
            },
            child: const Text('Add Event'),
          ),
          const SizedBox(height: 8.0),
          Expanded(child: _buildEventList()),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  // Simple TableCalendar configuration (using Styles)
  Widget _buildTableCalendar([List<Events>? events, List<Trxn>? trxns]) {
    return TableCalendar(
      firstDay: kFirstDay,
      lastDay: kLastDay,
      focusedDay: _focusedDay,
      selectedDayPredicate: (day) => isSameDay(_selectedDay, day),
      locale: 'en_US',
      eventLoader: (day) {
        return events ?? _getEventsForDay(day, events, trxns);
      },
      startingDayOfWeek: StartingDayOfWeek.sunday,
      calendarStyle: CalendarStyle(
        isTodayHighlighted: true,
        selectedDecoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.deepOrange[400]),
        todayDecoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.deepOrange[200]),
        markerDecoration: const BoxDecoration(color: Colors.deepPurpleAccent),
        outsideDaysVisible: false,
      ),
      headerStyle: HeaderStyle(
        formatButtonTextStyle:
            const TextStyle().copyWith(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 15.0),
        formatButtonDecoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.deepOrange[400],
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16.0),
        ),
      ),
      onDaySelected: (selectedDay, focusedDay) {
        setState(() {
          _selectedDay = selectedDay;
          _focusedDay = focusedDay; // update `_focusedDay` here as well
        });
      },
      onPageChanged: (focusedDay) {
        _focusedDay = focusedDay;
      },
    );
  }

  Widget _buildHolidaysMarker() {
    return Icon(
      Icons.add_box,
      size: 20.0,
      color: Colors.blueGrey[800],
    );
  }

  Widget _buildEventList() {
    final _db = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

    return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      stream: _db
          .collection('users')
          .doc(ref.read(globalsNotifierProvider).currentUserId)
          .collection('event')
          .where('eventDate',
              isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: DateTime(
                  _focusedDay.year, _focusedDay.month, _focusedDay.day, 0, 0))
          .where('eventDate',
              isLessThan: DateTime(_focusedDay.year, _focusedDay.month,
                  _focusedDay.day + 1, 0, 0))
          .snapshots(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData) {
          return const Center(
              child: Text(
            'Loading...',
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
          ));
        } else {
          var doc = snapshot.data!.docs;
          return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: doc.length,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                  child: ListTile(
                    isThreeLine: true,
                    title: Text(
                      '${doc[index]['eventName'] ?? 'n/a'}',
                      style: const TextStyle(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
                          color: Colors.blueAccent),
                    ),
                    subtitle: Text.rich(TextSpan(
                        text:
                            '${DateFormat('EE MM-dd-yyyy').format(doc[index]['eventDate'])}\n'
                            '${DateFormat('h:mm a').format(doc[index]['eventStartTime'])}, '
                            'Duration: ${doc[index]['eventDuration'] ?? 'n/a'} minutes',
                        children: <TextSpan>[
                          TextSpan(
                            text:
                                '\n${doc[index]['eventDescription'] ?? 'n/a'}',
                            style: const TextStyle(
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
                                color: Colors.blueGrey),
                          )
                        ])),
                    //trailing: Text('MLS#: ${_event.mlsNumber ?? 'n/a'}'),
                    onTap: () {
                      ref
                          .read(globalsNotifierProvider.notifier)
                          .updatenewEvent(false);
                      Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => AddEventScreen()));
                    },
                  ),
                );
              });
        }
      },
    );
  }

  Map<DateTime, List>? convertToMap(List<Events> item) {
    Map<DateTime, List>? result;

    for (int i = 0; i < item.length; i++) {
      Events data = item[i];
      //get the date and convert it to a DateTime variable
      //DateTime currentDate = DateFormat('MM-dd-yyyy - kk:mm').format(data.eventDate);
      DateTime currentDate = DateTime(
          data.eventDate!.year,
          data.eventDate!.month,
          data.eventDate!.day,
          data.eventDate!.hour,
          data.eventDate!.minute);

      List eventNames = [];
      //add the event name to the the eventNames list for the current date.
      //search for another event with the same date and populate the eventNames List.
      for (int j = 0; j < item.length; j++) {
        //create temp calendarItemData object.
        Events temp = item[j];
        //establish that the temp date is equal to the current date
        if (data.eventDate == temp.eventDate) {
          //add the event name to the event List.
          eventNames.add(temp.eventName);
        } //else continue
      }

      //add the date and the event to the map if the date is not contained in the map
      if (result == null) {
        result = {currentDate: eventNames};
      } else {
        result[currentDate] = eventNames;
      }
      return result;
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

I think one of my problems is with evenLoader: but I'm not sure.

Can I get some help please?
Thanks

UPDATE:
I have changed the code for eventLoader: but I am making any progress. I think this is the place where I a having the problem. The markers show up on the calendar but every day has the same markers.

Here is the change to my code:

```
eventLoader: (day) {
        int today = day.day;
        if (events == null) return [];
        DateTime eventDateUTC = events[today].eventDate!.toUtc();

        if (day.year == events[today].eventDate!.year &&
            day.day == events[today].eventDate!.day &&
            day.month == events[today].eventDate!.month) {
          List<Events> eventList = [];
          eventList.add(events[day.day]);

          return (kEvents.putIfAbsent(eventDateUTC, () => eventList));
        }
        return [];

        //return events ?? _getEventsForDay(day, events, trxns);
      },
```